# What are efficient advertising options for Android apps ported to BlackBerry Playbook?

Tags: android, admob, blackberry-playbook

I have ported/repackaged my free Android app to BlackBerry Playbook. Before publishing it to the AppWorld I removed AdMob from it as it wasn't clear at that point if that was going to be approved.

Now, developers trying to use AdMob on PlayBook report that ads are not being served on the platform, presumably due to lack of inventory for the PlayBook: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Plug-in-for-Android/No-Admob-in-Android-app/td-p/1373097

Does anyone have a success with serving ads in an Android app running on Playbook? If yes, was it AdMob, or something else?

Comment: I have the same problem but I did not remove AdMob before submitting (why should it be a problem?). My hope is that the PlayBook will start receiving ads once the users start using the app and generate more ad requests.

Answer (score 0):

I've ported an app without removing admob functionality. It got approved. Though requests are sending from the app, the app does not show any adds...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same 
Admob doesn't support blackberry at the moment..

this is a quite interesting thread on blackberry forum

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Plug-in-for-Android/No-Admob-in-Android-app/td-p/1373097